# JavaScript: Set Interval not working

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So basically I want to call a interval in a function while the function is being runned by another interval. This gives me the result I wasn't expecting. The console log should only be runned every third second but It's not.

My code:

```
// Define variable test
var test = 1;

// Setting function check on a 1000 ms interval
setInterval(function(){
    check();
}, 1000)

// If our variable test is == 1, set another interval on 3000ms on next function
function check() {
    if (test == 1) {
        setInterval(function(){
            execute();
        }, 3000)
    }
}

// Execute function
function execute() {
    console.log("Called every 3rd second!");
}
```

How can I fix this, spent hours trying to find solution and I'm really exhausted and have no idea how to continue.

If you want to post a answer I really appreciate it! But try not to destroy the structure in the code.

Edit: If you have Chrome, you can run this script in the console. You have to wait a few seconds before it runs.

Comment: Why would you think that running a timer that calls a function every second which starts a 3 second timer based on testing a value that never changes would do anything "every 3rd second"?

What's going to happen is you're going to have a whole lot of timers running on 3 second intervals... which is not even close to what you want.

Comment: @gforce301 This is a simplified version of a huge chunk of code I've made. So you guys can understand it better :)

Comment: So what you're saying is that your "huge chunk of code" is beyond our comprehension but you need the help of the simple minds found here? Show the code. I'm telling you that the code you showed won't do anything "every 3rd second". In fact after it runs for a while it will be doing things multiple times PER SECOND.

Comment: @gforce301 I only need to solve this problem to continue.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to run the function `execute` after every 3 seconds then you need to replace the first function `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. I am not sure why you need setInterval for the calling the `check` function.

Try out this code:

```js
 var test = 1;
    
    // Setting function check on a 1000 ms interval
    setTimeout(check, 1000)
    
    // If our variable test is == 1, set another interval on 3000ms on next function
    function check() {
        if (test == 1) {
            setInterval(execute, 3000)
        }
    }
    
    // Execute function
    function execute() {
        console.log("Called every 3rd second!");
    }
```